# Get path of file that is called

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose I've got following folder structure

```
/dir/dir2/dir3/program.exe
```

I want to obtain `program.exe` file path as it is called. E.g.

```
// program.exe
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << std::filesytem::current_path() << "\n";
}
```

But this `program.exe` works differently if called from different locations:

- being in `dir3`
  `user@command_line:/dir/dir2/dir3$ ./program.exe`
  output: `"/dir/dir2/dir3"`
- being in `dir2`
  `user@command_line:/dir/dir2$ ./dir3/program.exe`
  output: `"/dir/dir2"`
- being in `dir`
  `user@command_line:/dir$ ./dir2/dir3/program.exe`
  output: `"/dir"`

I wish I could obatin **exact path** of `program.exe` no matter what location is it called from. Is it possible?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Perhaps you can get what you need from a combination of `std::filesystem::current_path()` and what is inside `argv[0]`.

Comment: @KrzysiekKarbowiak That doesn't work if the program is found somewhere by using the environment's `PATH` variable. I don't think there's any 100% bullet proof way of getting the full path to the program currently being executed. `boost::filesystem::system_complete` may be one option.

Comment: "*I don't think there's any 100% bullet proof way of getting the full path to the program currently being executed*" - No *standard* way, no. But there are certainly *platform-specific* ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a folder with the working executable. Current path giving your a [process current directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory)

To obtain executable path

For Windows you can use [GetModuleFileNameA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea) Win API function:

For examle:

```
char  exe_name[ MAX_PATH+1 ] = {'\0'};
::GetModuleFileNameA(nullptr,exe_name,MAX_PATH);
```

For POSIX you can obtain executable path with [readlink](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) system call

For example:

```
char  exe_name[ PATH_MAX+1 ] = {'\0'};
char query[64] = {'\0'};
std::snprintf(query, 64, "/proc/%u/exe", ::getpid() );
::readlink(query, exe_name, PATH_MAX);
```

Comment: Sadly posix solution does not work for me ( it follows the pattern I descirbed in my problem ). Anyway thanks for the trouble.